# Editing $PATH in Linux

Tags: linux, path

I'm working on a linux client and I need to add my home directory path to $PATH but I was unable to do that.
I tried to find .bash_profile file and also .bashrc file but both are missing.
Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Just create the files on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article on understanding configuration files: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-config/index.html#4

The point is - like everyone else says:

- If it does not exist - create it.
- If process does not recognize it - restart the process.
- If it doesn't work - read the manual, may be that config file are not optional or you putted it into a wrong place (for example root user uses different configs due to home dir of root).

Answer (score 1):

If a `.bashrc` file doesn't exist, create one! Try adding one with this in it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME
```

Comment: Will it affect other users if I do. I want the $PATH name to be modified only for my username.

Comment: If the `.bashrc` file is in *your* home directory, it should affect only you.

Comment: How can I do this inside a perl script? Like if i want the $PATH to be changed only for that script means??

Comment: @Srikk: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Perl to help you with that. You can start a new question if you'd like.

Comment: I created .bash_profile with the above data you mentioned, but when I ran echo $PATH, my directory is not included. what to do?

Comment: @Srikk: I'm not quite sure why that wouldn't be working, but you may want to try adding a `.bash_login` file as well with this in it: `. ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If those files don't exist, you can simply create them.

Answer (score 0):

If `.bash_profile` doesn't exist in your home directory, you can always create it. To accomplish the goal of adding your home directory to the `$PATH` environment variable add a line similar to the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME
```